# How to upload an attachment to a list item using Microsoft.SharePoint.Client?

Tags: sharepoint

I am trying to create a new list item with an attachment. Bellow is my code:

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(_sharepointSite))
{
   clientContext.Credentials = _credentials;
   var list = clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListName");
   var listEntry = list.AddItem(new ListItemCreationInformation());
   listEntry["Title"] = model.Title;
   listEntry.Update();
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
   var attInfo = new AttachmentCreationInformation();
   attInfo.ContentStream = model.File.InputStream;
   attInfo.FileName = model.File.FileName;
   var attachment = listEntry.AttachmentFiles.Add(attInfo);
   clientContext.Load(attachment);
   clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

The list item creation code works fine but the file attachment code throws the following error:

```
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 2, position 1.
```

on the last clientContext.ExecuteQuery(). Does anyone have any ideas as to what the cause of this is?

UPDATE:

Here is my schema for the model:

```
public class UploadFileModel : IValidatableObject
{
    [Required, MaxLength(100), Display(Name = "File title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [Required, Display(Name = "User type")]
    public UserTypes? UserType { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), Display(Name = "Health care organization name")]
    public string HealthCareOrgName { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(100), Display(Name = "User's email")]
    public string UserEmail { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
}
```

Basically the File property is just the file the user is trying to upload...

Comment: Not sure but I believe that the `attInfo.ContentStream` should read the bytes from file. Something like `attInfo.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("streamFile"));`. Please to [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/96144/20540) and [this](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/119417/20540) answer. Also what type of object is `model` in your question?

Comment: @Naveen I have tried what you suggested (converting the stream to byte array and then back to MemoryStream) and that makes no difference. I have updated the question with the schema of my model. The file property is just a HttpPostedFile...